# Restriction Issue

Tags: performance, restriction, google-text-to-speech

We have developed an application that vocalizes content using a specific feature. However, while the voice feature works in Turkey and Germany, it does not work in America!

It seems there might be a restriction in place. The application is available on Google Play, but it's claimed that the voice feature does not work on iOS. I've tested it on my own iOS devices and it works.

However, it seems that it might not be working internationally, particularly in America. Can people living in America download the app using this link: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=masaloku.com.tr&hl=tr&gl=US and try using the voice feature?

It should start playing sound after 15-20 seconds. Thank you.